# Evaluate $\int_{1}^{e} x^{n} \ln x \mathrm{d} x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Evaluate the integral
$$
I=\int_{1}^{e} x^{n} \ln x \mathrm{~d} x, n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

**My Attempt:** Substitute $\ln x$ by $t$, then $x=e^t$, and so we need to evaluate the following integral:
$$
I=\int_0^1 e^{tn} t\,\mathrm d (e^t)
$$
Integrate by parts, we get
$$
I=t^2e^{t\left( n+1 \right)}\mid_{0}^{1}-\int_0^1{t\left( e^{t\left( n+1 \right)}+t\left( n+1 \right) e^{t\left( n+1 \right)} \right) \text{d}t}
$$
Thus it seems to be more complicated!

So, **my question is**, how to evaluate this integral?

Comment: Just do it by parts with $u=\ln x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $n \ne -1$, we use integration by parts:
$$\begin{align}\int x^{n} \ln x \mathrm{~d} x &= \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}\ln x - \frac{1}{n+1}\int x^{n+1}\frac 1 xdx \\&= \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}\ln x - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}x^{n+1} + C \end{align}$$
Else, we use the substitution $u = \ln x$:
$$\int \frac{\ln x}{x}dx = \frac{1}{2}\ln^2 x + C$$

Answer (score 2):

If $n\ne -1$, simply use integration by part,
$$\begin{align}
\int_1^ex^n\ln(x)\;dx &= \frac{1}{n+1}\int_1^e\ln(x)\;dx^{n+1} \\
&= \frac{1}{n+1}\ln(x)x^{n+1}\bigg|_1^e-\frac{1}{n+1}\int_1^ex^{n+1}\;d\ln(x) \\
&= \frac{e^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\int_1^ex^n\;dx \\
&= \frac{e^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{e^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \\
&=\frac{ne^{n+1}+1}{(n+1)^2}
\end{align}$$
If $n=-1$, then
$$\int_1^e\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\;dx=\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(x)\bigg|_1^e=\frac{1}{2}$$
Actually, by L'Hopital's rule,
$$\lim_{n\to -1}\frac{ne^{n+1}+1}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
so the formula
$$\int_1^ex^n\ln(x)\;dx=\frac{ne^{n+1}+1}{(n+1)^2}$$
is valid even if $n=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Call that integral $I_n$ instead so$$e^n=[x^n\ln x]_1^e=\int_1^e(x^{n-1}+nx^{n-1}\ln x)dx=\frac{e^n-1}{n}+nI_{n-1}$$and $I_{n-1}=\frac{(n-1)e^n+1}{n^2}$, i.e.$I_n=\frac{ne^{n+1}+1}{(n+1)^2}$. The only case this doesn't deal with is$$I_{-1}=\int_1^e\frac{\ln x}{x}dx=[\tfrac12\ln^2x]_1^2=\tfrac12.$$